# Image quality very low when images fetched from Facebook and written to SD.

Tags: java, android, facebook, image

I am fetching images from Facebook and writing them to SD card, but the image quality is very low. Following is my code to fetch and write:

```
try
        {
            URL url = new URL(murl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

            data1 = String.valueOf(String.format(getActivity().getApplicationContext().getFilesDir()+"/Rem/%d.jpg",System.currentTimeMillis()));

            FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(data1);

            ByteArrayOutputStream outstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outstream);
            byte[] byteArray = outstream.toByteArray();

            stream.write(byteArray);
            stream.close();


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The following code I use to display the same image:

```
                    File IMG_FILE = new File(IMAGE_CONTENT);
                    B2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    options.inScaled = false;
                    options.inDither = false;
                    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(IMG_FILE.getAbsolutePath(),options);
                    iM.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

The quality is still low even after using Options. What can be done to improve this?

Answer (score 2):

**to Save image from URL onto SD card  use this code**

```
try
{   
  URL url = new URL("Enter the URL to be downloaded");
  HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
  urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);                   
  urlConnection.connect();                  
  File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile();
  String filename="downloadedFile.png";   
  Log.i("Local filename:",""+filename);
  File file = new File(SDCardRoot,filename);
  if(file.createNewFile())
  {
    file.createNewFile();
  }                 
  FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
  InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
  int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
  int downloadedSize = 0;   
  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
  int bufferLength = 0;
  while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) 
  {                 
    fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);                  
    downloadedSize += bufferLength;                 
    Log.i("Progress:","downloadedSize:"+downloadedSize+"totalSize:"+ totalSize) ;
  }             
  fileOutput.close();
  if(downloadedSize==totalSize) filepath=file.getPath();    
} 
catch (MalformedURLException e) 
{
  e.printStackTrace();
} 
catch (IOException e)
{
  filepath=null;
  e.printStackTrace();
}
Log.i("filepath:"," "+filepath) ;
return filepath;
```

**use this code to set sdcard image as your imageview bg**

```
File f = new File("/mnt/sdcard/photo.jpg");
ImageView imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
imgView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

**else use this**

```
File file = ....
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
imgView.setImageURI(uri);
```

**You can directly show image from web without downloading it. Please check the below function . It will show the images from the web into your image view.**

```
public static Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) {
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
        return d;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

then set image to imageview using code in your activity.

Comment: My requirement is of saving it, because some other images in my list are displayed from memory and interchanging that between web and memory will render my list useless.

Comment: use the above code to save image to sdcard from web url.in the above code you are saving the image as raw byte.so that you quality of image wont be reduced.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're dealing with a lossy format (JPG) and are re-compressing the image. Even with quality at `100` you still get loss - you just get the least amount.

Rather than decompressing to a `Bitmap` then re-compressing when you write it to the file, you want to download the raw bytes directly to a file.

```
...
InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(data1);

byte[] b = new byte[2048];
int length;

while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
    os.write(b, 0, length);
}

is.close();
os.close();
...
```